# Parameter layout

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have four parameters in my report. Now I want to configure the report to show only one parameter in every line. In this case I want to have 4 parameter rows.

Is this possible?

Comment: Bad news.  I've looked on and off for about 3 years and haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You can create a web page and build the parameters and pass them in yourself. Or a real hack is that you may be able you use a report with textboxes formatted to look like buttons which then link to your actual report.